# Highcharts area with data labels on others data labels

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, area

I'm making a chart like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Jr7fM/

the values ​​of the series are very close at the beginning

```
series: [{
            name: 'Asia',
            data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268]
        }, {
            name: 'Africa',
            data: [106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766]
        }, {
            name: 'Europe',
            data: [163, 203, 276, 408, 547, 729, 628]
        }, {
            name: 'America',
            data: [18, 31, 54, 156, 339, 818, 1201]
        }, {
            name: 'Oceania',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }]
```

but, values can't stay on others values, how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this solution is not supported, but you adapt this solution http://jsfiddle.net/menXU/6/.

```
 load: function() {
                    StaggerDataLabels(this.series);
                },
```